# How to set the default format for a route in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

With the default routing, the request /posts/:id gets mapped to the "show" action with `:format => "html"`.  I am using some xhtml elements in my show action which don't get rendered correctly unless the :content_type is set to xml.  I am currently getting around this by rendering show.xml.erb and setting the content_type manually as follows:

```
format.html { render :template => "/posts/show.xml.erb", 
             :locals => {:post => @post}, :content_type => "text/xml" }
```

This seems silly though.  How can I change `routes.rb` so that /posts/:id is routed with `format=>"xml"`? Thanks.

Comment: your question is confusing about the model: do you have plots or posts ?

Comment: oops, sorry.  its one model, call it posts.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

**Default format for requests:**

You can set the default format of a given route to xml using the defaults hash.

Examples:

```
# single match defaulting to XML (/plots/1 is the same as /plots/1.xml)
match 'posts/:id' => 'posts#show', :defaults => { :format => 'xml' }

# using resources, defaulting to XML (all action use XML by default)
resources :posts, :defaults => { :format => 'xml' }

# using resources and mixing with other options
resources :posts,
          :only => [:new, :create, :destroy],
          :defaults => { :format => 'xml' }
```

It's always a good idea to search the [official Ruby on Rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html), it's fairly in-depth and a very good first-stop resource for any routing issues.

Comment: You can also set the default format for a namespace and such like so:

`namespace :user, :defaults => {:format => 'json'}`

Comment: Awesome. Without the format set as above, I was getting 406 errors requesting xml even though everything else was cool in the controller.

Answer (score 27):

If you only want to support one format and treat all requests as that format, you could use a filter to change it:

```
before_filter :set_format

def set_format
  request.format = 'xml'
end
```

Comment: Yes. If you choose to use this solution rather than the routes way (see my answer), you should set the filter as a private method, per security concerns. -- note that this forces the format as where the routes way does not, just sets default.

Answer (score 16):

**Rails 4 and 5**: In your controller (e.g. `ApplicationController` if all whole application uses same format) add following:

```
  before_action :set_default_request_format

  def set_default_request_format
    request.format = :json unless params[:format]
  end
```

For **Rails 3** and older use `before_filter` instead of `before_action`.

Comment: before_action should be used for rails 4 and going forward; rails 3 is before_filter: https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods/before_action

Answer (score 6):

If you want to set the default format for a route, use `defaults` option:

```
resources :posts, defaults: { format: 'xml' }
```

But if you want to enforce every request to return a specific format, use `constraints` option:

```
resources :posts, constraints: lambda { |req| req.format == 'xml' }
```

See the documentation: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#request-based-constraints

Comment: The latter is what I came here looking for - quick note, I switched the lambda to use `==` and it worked perfectly, 404ing for other formats.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I edited the answer following your suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

I'm finding weird behaviour in Rails 5 if you use this:

```
{ format: :json }
```

In your `config/routes.rb` then even if JSON isn't set in your accept header, it still coerces the request to a JSON request, including for controller tests that have the `as: :html` option set. It's not really a big deal for me, so I'm not going to dig into why this is, but if someone figures it out, let me know and I'll update this answer.

Comment: I'm seeing this same thing. Pretty annoying.

Comment: I see this in Rails 6.1 as well. It ignores any `Accept` header sent to the action. It should be named `:force` as it prevents any other request type from being used.