# Force all received requests Content-Type to JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-api

I'm actually working on an API which uses Rails 4. I would like to set the `Content-Type` of a request to JSON if the client does not specify a media type in `Content-Type` header.

In order to get that behaviour I tried to add the following `before_action` in my `ApplicationController` :

```
def set_request_default_content_type
  request.format = :json
end
```

In my `RegistrationsController#create` method I have a breakpoint to check if everything is working. Well, the `request.format` trick does not work, despite the value is set to `application/json` it seems that the controller (or Rails internals) do not consider the received request's Content-Type as JSON.

I did a POST request with the following body (and no Content-Type) :

```
{"user" : {"email":"foobar@mail.net","password":"foobarfoo"}}
```

By debugging with Pry I see that :

```
 [2] api(#<V1::RegistrationsController>) _  request.format.to_s
 => "application/json"
 [3] api(#<V1::RegistrationsController>) _  params
 => {
       "action" => "create",
   "controller" => "v1/registrations"
 }
```

It means that Rails did not have considered my request with the request.format configured with `Mime::JSON`, but instead with `Mime::ALL` and so it didn't parse the request's JSON body. :(

Comment: i think you need use [wrap_parameters()](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/ParamsWrapper/ClassMethods/wrap_parameters) in you `ActionController`

Comment: `ActionController::ParamsWrapper` is enabled by default for the json format. But it doesn't work. At the moment I don't use MetalController but a classic Rails architecture with standard controllers.

Answer (score 2):

Check this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31408681/188574). It uses `constraints` as follows

```rb
defaults format: :json do
  # your v1/registration route here
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define a `any` type response inside the `respond_to` block, which will not restrict your controller to respond when request uri ends with `.json`, it also relief you from defining a response type explicitly and will keep, independently of request content-type, responding as you wish, example:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.any  {render :json => {foo: 'bar'}}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class V1::RegistrationsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json
end
```

Makes the default reponse format json

Comment: The question was about the request content-type, not the response content-type. The request content-type affects how the server interprets the request, e.g. parsing params.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [post](https://blog.eq8.eu/til/content-type-applicationjson-by-default-in-rails-5.html), it is possible to create some middleware that translates the header for `Content-Type: application/json`.

```rb
# config/application.rb
# ...
require './lib/middleware/consider_all_request_json_middleware'
# ...

module MyApplication
  # ...
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # ...
    config.middleware.insert_before(ActionDispatch::Static, ConsiderAllRequestJsonMiddleware)
    # ...
```

```rb
# lib/middleware/consider_all_request_json_middleware.rb

class ConsiderAllRequestJsonMiddleware
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    env["CONTENT_TYPE"] = "application/json" if env["CONTENT_TYPE"] == "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

    @app.call(env)
  end
end
```

I've tested it with a Rails 6 API-only project and it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use constraints in your `routes.rb` file to force the content_type.

Example on Rails 3:

```rb
match '/api/endpoint' => 'apis_controller#endpoint', constraints: lambda { |request| request.format = :json }
```

That line will make the `Content-Type` be `json` for all requests made to that route.

This **other solution** also worked for me when testing with `rspec 2.99` and `rspec-rails 2.99` on `rails 3.0.6`:

```rb
params = { username: 'username' }
post '/your_path', params.merge({format: 'json'}).to_json, { 'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json', 'HTTP_ACCEPT' => 'application/json' }
```

Answer (score -1):

you should be able to set the default format using routes: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#defining-defaults

```
resources :registrations, ... defaults: { format: 'json' }
```

see also: [How to set the default format for a route in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800219/how-to-set-the-default-)
format-for-a-route-in-rails?answertab=active#tab-top

---

Also maybe of interest:

- http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/respond_with
- http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/respond_to (interesting comment at the bottom of this page)

> Rails ignores the accept header when it contains “,/” or “/,” and returns HTML (or JS if it’s a xhr request).
>
> This is by design to always return HTML when being accessed from a browser.
>
> This doesn’t follow the mime type negotiation specification but it was the only way to circumvent old browsers with bugged accept header. They had he accept header with the first mime type as image/png or text/xml.

Comment: I already tried to use config/route.rb's default format parameter and it basically does the same thing than my before_action :

[2] api(#<V1::RegistrationsController>) _  request.format.to_s
=> "application/json"
[3] api(#<V1::RegistrationsController>) _  request.content_type
=> "text/plain"
[4] api(#<V1::RegistrationsController>) _  params
=> {
      "format" => :json,
      "action" => "create",
  "controller" => "v1/registrations"
}

:(

Comment: request.format does not change request.content_type

Comment: I see your issue, its with the request (content_type) not the response (format)

Comment: Yes only with the request ;)