# Rails make all routes default to format: :json

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can you make all routes default to `json`?

I have the following for an api scope but am wondering if you can do the same for the global scope?

```
  scope :api, defaults: {format: :json} do
    get "/search(/:query)(/:location)" => "search#index"
  end
```

For example all `user` resources would also default to `json`

```
resources :users
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use **`constraints`**

```
constraints format: :json do
  resources :users
end
```

**or**

```
resources :users, :defaults => { :format => 'json' }
```

Comment: I accepted the answer and thought it worked but have created another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31421101/rails-routes-constraints-not-working-as-expected because it is not working as expected

Answer (score 4):

According to [Rails docs](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#defining-defaults), in your `config/routes.rb` file:

```
defaults format: :json do
  resources :photos
end
```