# Too may redirects rails respond_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, respond-to

I have a controller action method that gets all records of establishments from the DB, I then want to share this response with a external entity which is a RhoMobile application, i used respond_to to format the response to JSON.

```
def index
  @establishments = Establishment.index(params).includes(:assessor)
  @json_establishments = Establishment.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to(establishments_url) }
    format.json { render json: @json_establishments.as_json }
  end
end
```

When i navigate to this action i get an error

> **net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS**

in chrome developer tools on the console tab.

When i remove the `{ redirect_to(establishments_url) }` next to the *format.html* it's working with a status of **406 (Not Acceptable)** but if i would use the search in the action view that i created and click the browsers back button, i get something like:

> ```
> ActionController::UnknownFormat in EstablishmentsController#index
>
> ActionController::UnknownFormat
> <div class="source hidden" id="frame-source-0">
>   <div class="info">
>     Extracted source (around line <strong>#219</strong>):
>   </div>
> ```

instead and when i refresh the page i get the expected view.

Comment: I am redirecting to establishments_url because i want to go there after i do the search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No wonder that it is stuck in redirect loop.

**Reason**:

`establishments_url` points to `EstablishmentsController#index`, and your default format must have been `html`. So, after setting the variables, it redirects to `establishments_url`, which again tries to load `EstablishmentsController#index`.

**Solution**:

Instead of redirecting to the URL, you need to consider rendering a view (as you did in JSON format).

```
format.html { render 'establishments/index' }
```

Comment: I still get the ActionController::UnknownFormat text when i click back after the serach

Comment: @Teebo can you try appending `.html` in the URL?

Comment: Thanks a lot, but there has to be a better way

Comment: @Teebo, yes of course there is. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800219/how-to-set-the-default-format-for-a-route-in-rails) about setting default format of rails routes.